# Will commented out CSS still have an impact/overhead of processing?

Tags: css

Will commented out CSS still have an impact/overhead of processing when the page is being rendered by the browser?

Or should we always aim to be as clean as possible?

Comment: According to what I know, it still increases the size of the code (even extra spaces and line-breaks do). But in today's world where the internet connections are decent to say at least, wouldn't keep it a problem. And sure you can always use a minify-tool to remove comments and such from the version you put on the server and load on your page.

Comment: @ProDexorite Thanks for the responses. Make it an actual answer, so I can vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as the CSS parser has to determine where each comment starts and where it ends, yes, but literally no more than that.

You're better off worrying about conserving bytes — if you *do* worry about that, then all you have to do is put your CSS through a minifier that strips out all comments, and serve the minified stylesheet to your users while keeping the comments in your developer copy of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Comments (as well as spaces and line-breaks) increase the byte-size of the CSS-document, so basically if you're seeking to use a very well compressed files, you would want to [minify the CSS](http://cssminifier.com/) and strip off all comments.